# Photoshop license

Tags: adobe-photoshop, osx-mountain-lion

I Need some help wich Photoshop version I should choose.

Is it possible to install Version 4.0 5.0 6.0 or 7.0 on a New MacBook with 10.10 ?

Somebody offered me an old license and an upgrade to CS3. But I do not know if this will work in 10.10.

Has anyone experience with this topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe CS3 was the first Intel version.
It's been known to just about behave under Mavericks & later, with some tweaking to Java to get Illustrator running.

[Ref: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1610061 & other similar Googlings]

Nothing earlier than CS3 will even launch on a modern machine.

Comment: Do I need to install the old Software before I can upgrade it?

Comment: It won't run. It would need Rosetta, afaik, which was removed from the OS with perhaps Lion… You'd have to investigate how to download CS3 itself & license once running.